# Odd HttpRequest behaviour

Tags: asp.net, request, httphandler, webclient, uploaddataasync

I have a web service which runs with a HttpHandler class. In this class, I inspect the request stream for form / query string parameters. In some circumstances, it seemed as though these parameters weren't getting through. After a bit of digging around, I came across some behaviour I don't quite understand. See below:

```
// The request contains 'a=1&b=2&c=3'
// TEST ONLY: Read the entire request
string contents;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
{
    contents = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
// Here 'contents' is usually correct - containing 'a=1&b=2&c=3'. Sometimes it is empty.

string a = context.Request["a"];

// Here, a = null, regardless of whether the 'contents' variable above is correct
```

Can anyone explain to me why this might be happening? I'm using a .NET WebClient and UploadDataAsync to perform the request on the client if that makes any difference.

If you need any more information, please let me know.

Comment: Why don't you use `context.Request.QueryString`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you inspecting the request stream for query string parameters? There are a lot of built in types within .Net to deal with HTTP Requests. You can easily get a proper NameValueCollection from the querystring with the following code;

```
NameValueCollection queryStringValues =
    HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpContext.Current.Request.Query.ToLower());

string value = queryStringValues["my_key"];
```

In your code you have a `StreamReader` read the stream and assign this to a string variable called `contents`. However when you assign the value to string `a` you access a variable called `context` which I assume is really `HttpContext.Current`. You then use the `Request` object as a `NameValueCollection`. When you access the `Request` collection like that it looks for both POST and GET parameters checking both `Request.Form` and `Request.QueryString`.

Unless something further up the HTTP request pipeline is changing the request enroute you won't loose parameters. Use a proxy tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to inspect the request as it leaves the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wasn't checking for query string parameters, I was checking the Request for either GET or POST data (i.e. Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded). In this circumstance, the data is POST-ed, so I'd expect using the Request[] indexer to check both the QueryString and Form collections. But it doesn't seem to. 

I'm currently getting around it by using GET parameters instead incidently, but I'd much prefer to use POST if I could get it working correctly.